# How to use Store Procedure in ASP.NET MVC using entity framework, repository pattern and create role base access on given sp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

How to use Store Procedure in ASP.NET MVC using entity framework, repository pattern and create role base access on given sp. Ihave to create role base access using the below sp, I am new ,i am not getting exact idea how to create and use this store procedure .Thank you

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AccountAccess] 
    @UserName NVARCHAR(255), @Password NVARCHAR(255)

    AS

    SELECT CASE WHEN (
SELECT UserType
    FROM (SELECT Username, Password, 'Admin' UserType 
            FROM AccountAccess AC
            WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM v_Admins AD WHERE AD.Email = AC.Email)
            UNION ALL

            --Sales by Department
            SELECT Username, Password, 'Department' UserType
            FROM AccountAccess AC
            WHERE SalesView <> ''
            AND  AC.Department <> SalesView
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM v_AllUser AD WHERE AD.Email = AC.Email)
            AND Email NOT LIKE '%process%'
            AND Email <> ''
            AND Password <> ''
            UNION ALL

            --sales by sales
            SELECT Username, Password, 'sales' UserType
            FROM AccountAccess AC
            WHERE SalesView = ''
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM v_AllUser AD WHERE AD.Email = AC.Email)
            AND Email NOT LIKE '%process%'
            AND Email <> ''
            AND Password <> ''
            UNION ALL

            --provision 
            SELECT Username, Password, 'provision' UserType
            FROM AccountAccess AC
            WHERE AC.provision <> ''
            AND (ProvisionView = '' OR AC.provision = ProvisionView)
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM v_AllUser AD WHERE AD.Email = AC.Email)
            AND Email NOT LIKE '%process%'
            AND Email <> ''
            AND Password <> '') T
    WHERE Username = @UserName COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
    AND Password = @Password COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
    GROUP BY UserType) IS NULL THEN 'FAILURE' Else 'SUCCESS' END AS LogonGranted,
    (SELECT UserType
    SELECT UserType
    FROM (SELECT Username, Password, 'Admin' UserType 
            FROM AccountAccess AC
            WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM v_Admins AD WHERE AD.Email = AC.Email)
            UNION ALL

            --Sales by Department
            SELECT Username, Password, 'Department' UserType
            FROM AccountAccess AC
            WHERE SalesView <> ''
            AND  AC.Department <> SalesView
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM v_AllUser AD WHERE AD.Email = AC.Email)
            AND Email NOT LIKE '%process%'
            AND Email <> ''
            AND Password <> ''
            UNION ALL

            --sales by sales
            SELECT Username, Password, 'sales' UserType
            FROM AccountAccess AC
            WHERE SalesView = ''
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM v_AllUser AD WHERE AD.Email = AC.Email)
            AND Email NOT LIKE '%process%'
            AND Email <> ''
            AND Password <> ''
            UNION ALL

            --provision 
            SELECT Username, Password, 'provision' UserType
            FROM AccountAccess AC
            WHERE AC.provision <> ''
            AND (ProvisionView = '' OR AC.provision = ProvisionView)
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM v_AllUser AD WHERE AD.Email = AC.Email)
            AND Email NOT LIKE '%process%'
            AND Email <> ''
            AND Password <> '')
```

Comment: are you EF using Database First? or Class first?

Comment: Entity framework Code first and repository pattern we are using .